# How to change my variable in a function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Why cant i change the variable visibile in my function? So at the moment the page echos ahello.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var visible= 'a';
$(document).ready(function(){
visible='1';

 $('input[type="checkbox"]').not('.singleobsyes').hide();

     $('.singleobsyes').on("change", function(){  
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not('.singleobsyes').toggle();   
visible='2';        
     });   

});
<?php $visible = "<script>document.write(visible)</script>"?>  
</script>ible in my function.
<?php
echo $visible."hello";?>
```

If so then pleas can you tell me how i can get my variable visible to change to 1 if it goes into the first function and 2 if it goes into the second function. So it echos 1hello and 2 hello respectively?

Comment: You are mixing Javascript and PHP and seem to be confused about what's executed server-sided and what's client-sided. `visible` is a Javascript variable and `$visible` a PHP variable. The first is only accessible for the users web browser and the second only for the PHP interpreter on the server.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Variables are **NOT** JavaScript variables. You pass currently the string visible to $visible, and not the content of it.

You misunderstood some basic stuff here.

Comment: <?php $visible = "<script>document.write(visible)</script>"?>  
 He is defining $visible in PHP!!  But still - this is some weird stuff !! :)

Comment: Yeah but he tries document.write(visible), I think he wants to use the JS Variable visible there, since he defined it above.